# Building a climbing structure for cats

Tags: building

Hoping to get a bit of DIY advice.

We have a cat enclosure around the side of our house with a tin shed in it (see the photograph). We're trying to give the cats a way of accessing the roof of the shed.

The problem is creating a secure structure that the cats could climb on. I don't think it would be possible to attach an outside shelf to the tin shed. My partner has thought about building a bridge from the opposite wall, but I'm a bit skeptical that would work. Finally, there is a short brick wall that could possibly be used as a secure base for a structure, but I'm not sure how. On the other side of the shed, there is empty space where a structure could possibly be erected.

Any thoughts on what we could do?

[image]

[Photograph of enclosure](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wmez2kpto92hvt2/20210911_172239.jpg?dl=0)

Comment: If you own the property, plant a tree by the shed, cats love it.

Comment: Would a plank of wood attached to the same wall as the shelves and going to the apex of the shed roof be too unsightly? Two small pieces of wood at the shed end would add some lateral stability if the cats decide to jump off the walkway.

Comment: Find an old tree bark that is long enough will do too.

Comment: Are your cats actual lions? House cats typically only weigh up to about 12 lbs. A stack of cardboard boxes taped together is secure enough for most cats. You are way over thinking this.